# Prove the sum of two rational number is equal to $\frac{e}{lcm(b,d)}$ for some integer $e$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, rational-numbers

As title state: 
$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{lcm(b,d)}$ for some integer $e$.
Here is what I tried:

$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ Since $gcd(b,d)lcm(b,d)=bd$, so I got $\frac{ad+bc}{gcd(b,d)lcm(b,d)}$. Since these are two rational numbers, so $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$, then by Bezout's identity: $ad+bc=gcd(b,c)$, so $\frac{gcd(b,d)}{gcd(b,d)lcm(b,d)} = \frac{1}{lcm(b,d)}$, therefore there exist an integer $e$ such that $e=1$.

That's my proof, I think there is an error within it, because I can't find an example support this proof... Can someone help me to point out where my errors are? Appreciate all helps.

Comment: It's not $ad+bc=(b,d)$, but rather $ad+bc=k(b,d)$.  I'm fairly certain that Bezout's identity has different conditions.

Comment: What does k(b, d) mean? gcd(b,d) was a scalar k?  But my text book doesn't state in this way...

Comment: A counterexample for your proof: Let $A=1/4$ and $B=1/6$ be two rational numbers and we have $A+B= 1/4+1/6=5/12=5/lcm(4,6)$. Also, there is a similar type of question where e=1 is valid, just for extra knowledge check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/941157/610697)

Comment: It's not that $k$ is a function, but rather $(a,b)$ is shorthand for $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ and after that $k$ is just a scalar value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not correct, because Bézout's identity doesn't say that.

However, it can be corrected. It follows from what you did that$$\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{a\frac d{\gcd(b,d)}+c\frac b{\gcd(b,d)}}{\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)}$$and, since $a$, $\frac d{\gcd(b,d)}$, $c$, and $\frac b{\gcd(b,d)}$ are all integers, you can just take$$e=a\frac d{\gcd(b,d)}+c\frac b{\gcd(b,d)}\in\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: Some of your fractions are upside down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am afraid my understanding of this subject is not that advanced yet... I can't see how you get the RHS in the first step... can you show more details?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't think so, but I wrote several times $\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)$ where I should have written $\gcd(b,d)$. I've edited the answer. What do you think now?

Comment: @JiayeWang I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Ah, that works too :) But it's overcomplicating things. If you replace $d/\gcd(b,d)$ by $\lcm(b,d)/b$ etc., then you don't need the gcd-lcm relation, just the definition of the lcm.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the first step...Can you expand how you get the RHS of the equation in the first step?

Comment: \begin{align}\frac{ad+bc}{\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)\gcd(b,d)}&=\frac{\frac{ad+bc}{\gcd(b,d)}}{\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)}\\&=\frac{a\frac d{\gcd(b,d)}+c\frac b{\gcd(b,d)}}{\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)}.\end{align}Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)\gcd(b,d)=bd$, and so $\gcd(b,d)=bd/\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)$.

Then

$$\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}=\frac{ad+bc}{\operatorname{lcd}(b,d)\gcd(b,d)}.$$

Of course, $\gcd(b,d)$ divides $d$ and $b$, and so
$$\frac{ad+bc}{\gcd(b,d)}=a\frac{d}{\gcd(b,d)}+c\frac{b}{\gcd(b,d)}$$
is an integer $e$.

Comment: $\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{ad}{bd}+\frac{bc}{bd}$

Comment: But why you change $bd$ to $\gcd(b,d)$?

Comment: As you said in your post, $bd=\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)\gcd(b,d)$.

Comment: But where is the $\text{lcm}(b,d)$...?

Comment: The last line is just the integer $e$. Then $\frac ac+\frac cd=\frac{e}{\operatorname{lcm}(b,d)}$